# Run Monogame exe without Visual Studios

Tags: web, playback, monogame

This is probably a stupid question but I am no the best with technology so I figured I might as well ask. I am working on creating a website for myself and I would like to put Monogame work on there. Is there a way I could I guess compress it all into one file for a person to download and then play it? or possibly make it playable via my website and how have them download anything?

This is my first post on her so sorry if this is not worded properly (it being 2:30 a.m. is not helping either). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot implement MonoGame as a game on your website. The closest you're gonna get is having it working over Local Network. And this has only been tested with XNA.

However yes, if you compile a complete version of your game and Zip it, that should work. As far as I've experienced, if you simply make sure to include MonoGame.Framework.Dll, it should work without any further requirements (apart of course from the standard ones, such as DirectX and .Net Framework in general).

You might want to test this on a clean computer (Virtual machine would also work I think). If this doesn't work, make an installer instead, using the Visual Studio Publish feature. I've never had that fail before

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I shall look more into this.